# transfer part of data from IBM cloud to Microsoft Azure

Tags: cloud, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, azure-iot-hub, watson-assistant

I am sending some sensor data to IBM cloud. 
Suppose I have three sensors A,B,C. 
Now I want to send data of only B & C sensor from IBM cloud to Microsoft Azure.
How to achieve the same .

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The link in your post shows the steps to create IBM Integration bus virtual image on Azure and how to import and deploy the IBM Integration bus image on Azure. The IBM Integration Bus is running in the Virtual Machine as a deployed service in Azure, data transfer is still between your device client and the IBM Bus service. If you want to transfer the data to Azure, you can use Azure IoT Hub SDKs to transfer the data. But I am not sure if the IBM cloud support the integration and Azure IoT Hub SDKs supports IBM cloud service.

Comment: @rose, have you checked that the IBM cloud service could integrate with Azure IoT Hub SDKs? Theoretically, it can implement that. Azure IoT Hub SDKs include C, C#, Java, Node.js, or Python without worrying about protocol specific intricacy. The SDKs provide out-of-box support for a range of platforms and the C SDK can be ported to new platforms.